# WordPress error. Sidebar not showing and WAMP shows error message "Undefined index"

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp, sidebar

I´m using the wordpress theme named Cake for create a Blog.

**First of all I added the sidebar widget:**

[image: screenshot1]

**Like this I can customize the sidebar widget:**

[image: screenshot2]

**However I refresh Blog page and I get the following error message (WAMP don´t display the sidebar):**

[image: screenshot3]

This is my file sidebar.php:

[image: screenshot2]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: er.. whats at line 17 of sidebar.php?  Did you make changes to that file? (or any changes at all to your template?)

Comment: I don´t make changes, is the default file of Cake template. I have edited the main post.

Comment: Dunno.  Can you contact the muffingroup via email, and ask them? (email address: muffingroupcom@gmail.com )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well add this line to debug what you have done.

```
$sidebar = get_post_meta( mnf_ID(), 'mnf-post-side-bar', true);
var_dump($sidebar);
var_dump($sidebars);
```

This will tell you what is being returned from that function call and wether it exists in the $sidebars array, and will probably explain the issue.